# Javascript rapid browser resize issue using angularjs, kendotabstrip and javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I have created an overflow for a kendotapstrip:

[image: kendotabstrip showing 3 tabs on the tabstrip and 2 tabs in the overflow]

The pic above shows the tabstrip with the browser window contracted. Three tabs are on the the tabstrip, two tabs are in the overflow.

I am using an angularJS directive to control the functionality.

I have bound a resize event to the window. As soon as you start re-sizing, a resizeTabstrip() function is called and tabs are hidden or shown (using css styling) on the tabstrip according to the amount of space available.

If there is too little space, a tab is hidden and added to an overflow array (which is set on the scope, scope.overflowTabs[]).

If there is enough space, the tab is removed from the overflow array and re-shown on the tabstrip.

This is my problem:

If you re-size up and down REALLY quickly, tabs are going missing:

[image: kendotabstrip showing the browser at full width but tabs missing from the tabstrip]

The pic above shows the tabstrip after a very quick re-size up/down with the browser window at full size but tab 2 is missing from the tabstrip.

This is the main resize bind that invokes the resizeTabstrip() function:

```
            angular.element(myWindow).bind('resize', function(e) {                    
                setTimeout(function() {
                    callResizeTabstrip();                        
                },500);
            });
```

As you can see, I am calling a variable callResizeTabstrip with a delay of 500ms. This variable is in turn assigned a function call to resizeTabstrip():

```
            var callResizeTabstrip = _.throttle(function(e) {
                resizeTabstrip();
            }, 500); // Maximum run of once per 500 milliseconds
```

resizeTabstrip() is inside an underscore.js _.throttle function, ensuring it is called once every 500ms.

Inside the resizeTabstrip() function, the main engine, I do this:

```
            function resizeTabstrip() {
               // get the tabstrip...
               // calculate the amount of space... <-- THE PROBLEM IS HERE I THINK
               // if very little space then...
               scope.moveTabToOverflow(tabstripId, tabTitle);
               // else if enough space
               scope.moveTabFromOverflow(tabstripId, scope.overflowTabs[tabstripId]);                    
            }
```

Lots of calculating is done, for every resize (and the resize event is fired LOADS). This is I think the is cause of the problem. Things move too quickly for the browser to handle.

Has anyone got any suggestions as to how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found an answer: trigger a custom event at the end of the timeout that checks the tabstrip and refreshes it so that all tabs are present and correct.

The trigger was acheived using a custom event (resizeEnd).

```
            angular.element(myWindow).bind('resize', function(e) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    callResizeTabstrip(); // the main function
                    $(this).trigger('resizeEnd'); // my custom event called afterwards
                },1000); // delay for 1 second
            });
```

Then I bound this custom event to the window. It gets all the tabs (hidden and visible) on the tabstrip and essentially reloads them:

```
            angular.element(myWindow).bind('resizeEnd', function() {
                // get the tabstrip using a jquery selector
                // get the id of the tabstrip, also using jquery ([attr="id"]            
                // get all tabs on this tabstrip but not tabs in the overflow
                var tabs = $('[id='+tabstripId+']               
                                          li:not(#overflowTab'+tabstripId+')');                     

                    $.each(tabs, function(index, tab) { // for each tab
                        // show the tab (css display: block)
                        showTabOnTabstrip(tabstripId, index); // ensures all tabs are placed back on the tabstrip                           
                    });                                      
            });
```